# How to write Firebase Realtime Database to Firestore automatically?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently doing a project that uses Arduino to collect data and store the data in cloud and display the data on cloud on mobile app. From what I have tried, Arduino can only upload data to Firebase realtime database, but my Flutter mobile app needs the data to be stored in Firestore. Is there any way to write firebase realtime database data into Firestore automatically when there is changes in the realtime database?

This is the realtime database structure:
[realtime database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58lkY.png)

and I would like to append the data into respective field in Firestore like this:
[firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH6cv.png)

I have tried to read the data every 5 seconds and write it to Firebase but it does not seems like very efficient:

```
final userDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("user/");
 String uid = globals.uid;

 Stream<DatabaseEvent> stream = userDbRef.onValue;

 // Subscribe to the stream!
 var subscription = stream.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
   // print('Listening');
   dynamic values = event.snapshot.value;
   final data = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(values);

   globals.temp = data['temp'];
   globals.hr = data ['hr'];
   globals.spo2 = data['spo2'];
   globals.position = data['position'];
   globals.time = DateTime.parse(data['time']);
 });

 subscription.pause();

 String date = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 8)).toString().substring(0, 10);

 dynamic result = await DatabaseService(uid: uid).getUserData('patient');
 if (result[date].toString() == 'null') {
   await DatabaseService(uid: uid).updateSingleUserData('patient', {
     date: {
       'time': ['${date} 00:00:00.000'],
       'hr': [95],
       'temp': [36.5],
       'spo2': [98],
       'position': ['lying'],
     },
   });
 } else {
   List timeList = result[date]['time'];
   List hrList = result[date]['hr'];
   List tempList = result[date]['temp'];
   List spo2List = result[date]['spo2'];
   List positionList = result[date]['position'];

   if ((!timeList.contains(globals.time.toString())) & (globals.time.toString() != 'null')) {
     timeList.add(globals.time.toString());
     hrList.add(globals.hr);
     tempList.add(globals.temp);
     spo2List.add(globals.spo2);
     positionList.add(globals.position);

    await DatabaseService(uid:uid).updateSingleUserData('patient', {
       date: {
         'time': timeList,
         'hr': hrList,
         'temp': tempList,
         'spo2': spo2List,
         'position': positionList,
       },
     });
   }
 }
 subscription.resume();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to write firebase realtime database data into
> Firestore automatically when there is changes in the realtime
> database?

Yes, a common approach is to use a Cloud Function that is **automatically** [triggered each time a new node is added to the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). The Cloud Function is executed in the back-end, i.e. on the Firebase/Google Cloud infrastructure, and therefore you don't need to write any code in your Flutter app for this data mirroring/transfert.

Here is a simple example with generic paths:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and set up triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.duplicateToFirestore = functions.database.ref('/myRTDBPath/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const nodeVal = snapshot.val();

      // Write it to a Firestore collection

      return admin.firestore().collection('myFirestoreCollection').add(nodeVal);

    });
```

---

I let you do the work of transformation of the RTDB node value to the Firestore document structure you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Renaud Tarnec, this looks really interesting. I'm a data analyst and need to connect data from a Real time db to Looker Data Studio. I've seen your video. However, the BigQuery extension only works with collections, as many pointed out in other posts. I'm totally new to Firebase, so if you can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. I don't know where to begin, for example, the sample code you posted above, where is it supposted to go?

Comment: Hi @NicolásLopedeBarrios, you could write a Cloud Function which mirrors the RealTime Database (RTDB) data to BigQuery. If you still want to use the Firestore to BigQuery extension you can mirror the RTDB data to Firestore with a Cloud Function similar to the one in my answer. So the code above is [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions?hl=en) code. Doing RTDB => Firestore => BigQuery will add the Firestore cost to your bill but will be a bit easier than writing a Cloud Function which mirrors the RTDB data to BigQuery

Comment: @NicolásLopedeBarrios PS: to interact between a Cloud Function and BigQuery you need to use the [BigQuery Client Library for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/latest)

Comment: But, once data is in a Firebase collection, can't I just use the extension, like you describe in the video?

Comment: "once data is in a Firebase collection, can't I just use the extension, like you describe in the video?" => Yes!

Comment: So to summarize you have two possible approaches: RTDB ===YourCloud Function===> Firestore ===Extension===> BigQuery   **OR**   RTDB ===YourCloud Function===> BigQuery. Note btw that the extension is based on a Cloud Function :-)

Comment: @NicolásLopedeBarrios. Were you able to find a solution to connect Firebase RTBD with Looker Studio? I am looking for the exact same thing. From Renaud's answer, apparently making the RTDB - Cloud Functions - Big Query - Looker Studio connection seems to be the most straightforward.

Comment: Hi @DavidL, I had to shift to another project so this is on pause right now, but will address it eventually. I'll update this post